# Effect of variable type in prediction

Tags: random-forest

Let's say I have a set of independent variables: `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, etc. These are used to predict a dependent variable `y` using some algorithm (in particular Random Forest).

How does the accuracy of the model depend on the type of those variables, say categorical variable or integer or character?

Comment: the accuracy of the model depends on the strength of relationship between those variables and dependent variables, instead of the type of those variables.

Comment: so it does not matter what kind of type i use in building model , right ?

Comment: Need to keep the original type of the variable. Generally, do not convert the continue variable into categorical variable.